# Calculating Irradiance Using Spherical Harmonics from Cubemap into a Cubemap?

Tags: directx

I'm trying to figure out how to make an irradiance map using spherical harmonics, but i want the output to be a cubemap rather than just rendering an object. There is the (deprecated) D3DX11SHProjectCubeMap but even then i don't know how it'd be used. It seems the output is just an array of colors, but it doesn't specify any details of how the function works or what the output is. Does it just output some sort of image that i'd then need to convert to a cubemap?